# Multiple OAUTH providers in .NET app how to handle identical querystring?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-graph-api, oauth, instagram

I am creating a .NET app and on one of my screens I have different services to hook up to using OAUTH.

An example of two are Facebook and Instagram. I allow the user to authorize my app access to these applications. Everything is working fine individually however I cannot figure out a good way to know which provider the user selected(I have a simple button click for each service) on callback since both Facebook and Instagram both return "code" on the querystring. Which is then used to do the final step of the OAUTH authorization.

I tried storing the button clicks of each service in session however my session is getting wiped on the redirect to the providers authorization URL and on the return to my app on the callback (and yes even with Redirect(url, false) my session is still getting cleared). So basically I have no clue what button the user clicked with the service the authorization is coming back from (Facebook or Instagram).

Any thought or ideas to know after a user authenticates my app and the callback is made how to know what provider sent me that callback in code behind?

Answer (score 3):

Can't you have them go to different callback URLs? Is there a reason why they need to go to the same URL?

Comment: For convenience I have them all calling back to my "Connections" page. It is sort of a maintenance page where you would set up all your providers b/c I plan to have a good amount of services in my app. So if I can keep the same callback would be ideal.

Comment: Just have a pass-through URL for each provider. So you have \oauth-callback-facebook and \oauth-callback-twitter, etc that simply forwards the data along with an additional parameter that says which provider you received the callback from.

Answer (score 0):

You could include this info in the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Request's [`state` parameter](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.1.1) (which you should already use to prevent CSRF attacks), e.g. by appending a `_fb` or `_ig` to it.

However, the more convenient way would be to have different callbacks.

Comment: Hmm interesting but I am also having the same problem with twitter and tumblr having the same querystring param(oauth_token) on authorization callback and those aren't on 2.0 yet.

Comment: You could try if your OAuth 1 providers support returning additional query parameters in the callback URL (e.g. `https://domain.com/callback?provider=facebook`) or setting a cookie when the user clicks the login button before redirecting to the providers authorization endpoint.

Comment: The additional parameters in the query string did the trick! Thanks